# after user went offline still it shows typing notification in ejabberd

Tags: push-notification, ejabberd

i am using ejabberd server for chat application. The scenario is user A and user B doing chat. user B goes offline and then come online. user B get the all  message with push  notifiacation. **But the issue is when user B goes offline still user A get typing notification from ejabberd.** anyone can help me in this. It there any feature in ejabberd to handle this notification or i have to use filter and client side.

Answer (score 0):

Typing notification is defined in [XEP-0085: Chat State Notifications](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html). It is purely client-side.

Clients are supposed to send update about their own state, but of course, the right thing to do for a receiving client is also to dismiss the typing indication when a resources get offline.